# Why is System Restore turned off by default in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, system-restore, windows-restore

In the past I used system restore many times to repair failed updates, software installations gone wrong, etc.
I found the tool very useful. Restoring the system to an earlier time has saved me hours.
Why has this been disabled by default?
Is there an alternative to System Restore?

Comment: I am not sure. I have a Windows 10 production laptop with System Restore set to ON disk space usage at 10 GB.  The laptop has all normal partitions. I have a Windows 10 Insider machine where System Restore is OFF (also set earlier in its life to 10 GB).  It says "Using System protection on a drive that contains the system image will cause shadow copies to be deleted faster than normal"  I see what you see - I do not know why. I will change my Insider machine and see what happens.

Comment: I just checked my Windows 10 production Desktop and System Restore is ON.  It seems to be a bug in Windows Insider and will likely get fixed.